# No access to constant defined in Google Sheets library

Tags: google-apps-script

I am testing the use of libraries for a first project I want to run in Google Sheets.
I created a Google Sheet, with just a single button (a drawing) in it. To this button, I assigned my script ‘myFunction’.

This ‘myFunction’

1. Calls ‘justMyTestFunction’ in library Tlib
2. Logs a locally defined constant string (logInfo) to the Logger
3. Logs a string, defined in library Tlib, to the Logger

Below you see the content of my Google Sheet Script

```
const logInfo = 'This is a local sentence; not stored in any library';

function myFunction() {
  TLib.justMyTestFunction();
  Logger.log(logInfo);
  Logger.log(TLib.logSentence);
}
```

And you see the content of my Tlib library

```
const logSentence = 'This sentence is stored as a constant in library TestLibrary...';

function justMyTestFunction() {
  Logger.log('This sentence is hardcoded in function justMyTestFunction of library Tlib...');
}
```

When clicking the button in my Google sheet, the result is the following Logger information:

```
Stackdriver-logboeken
31 aug. 2020 22:11:25   Informatie  This sentence is hardcoded in function justMyTestFunction of library Tlib...
31 aug. 2020 22:11:25   Informatie  This is a local sentence; not stored in any library
31 aug. 2020 22:11:25   Informatie  null
```

From which I conclude:

1. The call to ‘justMyTestFunction’ in library Tlib was successful
2. The access to the locally defined string was successful and could be logged (of course )
3. The access to the string defined in the library (Tlib.logSentence) was not successful. As a result, the null value is sent to the Logger

What I cannot understand : apparently the link with the library is OK, because my Sheet can access and execute the function ‘justMyTestFunction’.
But the same Sheet has no access to a ‘global’ constant, that was defined in this library.
Obviously I am missing something trivial here. But I am ‘out of ideas’. Can anyone point me to the cause of the problem and its solution ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the current stage, when `const` is used in the library as the global variable, the value cannot be retrieved from the client. I think that this might be resolved in the future update. So as the current workaround, please use `var` instead of `const` as follows.

#### From:

```
const logInfo = 'This is a local sentence; not stored in any library';
```

#### To:

```
var logInfo = 'This is a local sentence; not stored in any library';
```

After above modification, please test it again. When the developer mode of the installed library is "ON", you will be able to test the modified script.

#### Reference:

- [Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)

Comment: Hello Tanaike, thanks a lot for your prompt reply! I will surely test it, and come back with my findings.

Comment: Changing `const` to `var` solved the issue perfectly. Thanks! This is a solid workaround until the issue is taken care of in one of the future updates.